# ruby system call to restart delayed job is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, system-calls

My delayed job processes seem to randomly disappear, I am working on a longer term fix for this, but in the mean time, I think simply restarting them when I need them should do the trick. Since I have a ruby batch job that needs delayed job to process when its running, I thought I would just restart the delayed job processes at the start using:

```
system_call_result = system( "RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/delayed_job -n7 restart" )
```

This doesnt work, the call returns false and it does nothing. So I also tried:

```
system_call_result1 = system( "RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/delayed_job stop" )
system_call_result2 = system( "RAILS_ENV=production ruby script/delayed_job -n7 start" )
```

Again this doesn't work.

I haven't done many system calls so im sure its something basic.

I did: >> foo = "system("ls -la")

and it lists files in the base rails directory, so it seems like im in the right spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefixing a command with environment variables isn't a proper command (I think it's a bashism, but I could be wrong).  You could do a few different things:

1. Nothing, if `RAILS_ENV` is already set to production (child processes inherit their parent's environment).
2. Set the `RAILS_ENV` to production in `ENV` so that it does get inherited (`ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "production")`
3. Use the `env` command, which allows you to alter the environment a program runs in

   ```
    system "env RAILS_ENV=production ruby ..."
   ```

   (or you could wrap your command in bash so that the environment-prefix works... `system 'bash -c "RAILS_ENV=production ruby ..."`)